# How to print elements from array still again?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

len=$1    
numbers=("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9")

for i in $(seq 0 $len)    
do      
      echo -n ${numbers[i]}    
done    
echo
```

When I run it: ./script 9

I get this result -

```
0123456789
```

It's okay, but what, if I want to have this output?

```
012345678901234567890123456789
```

Once it printed last element from the array of numbers, so, how to let it printing again from the first one again?

Comment: add an outer loop to run the inner loop 3 times. i.e.  `for j in {1..3}` ...

Comment: Ignore the comment above if you're not iterating the array completely for each round.

Comment: Unrelated, but try to avoid the use of `seq` in scripts. In `bash`, you can use C-style for loops (`for((i=0; i <= $len; i++))`). If you need POSIX compatibility, you *still* can't use `seq`, since it is not part of the POSIX standard; use a `while` loop instead (`i=0; while [ "$i" -le "$len" ]; do ...; i=$((i+1)); done`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modular arithmetic on the array index.

```
len=$1    
numbers=("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9")

for i in $(seq 0 $len)    
do      
      echo -n ${numbers[i % ${#numbers[@]}]}    
done    
echo
```

For instance, with 10 numbers in the array, when `i` reaches ten, you want to use `10 % 10 == 0` as the array index.

Comment: Ah similar answer but you were 12 seconds faster +1

Comment: What a nice solution. Thanks for the fast response and help.